# Any up to date tutorial on how to setup Postfix + Dovecot with virtual users on Debian?

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

Any up to date tutorial (for dummys) on how to setup Postfix + Dovecot with virtual users on Debian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked for "up to date", so something from 2007 shouldn't be too far off: 
http://workaround.org/articles/ispmail-etch/

If that's too old, then it doesn't look like there's 1 specific tutorial covering what you're looking for (maybe you could write one when you get done?) but a combination should work:

No date given, and not debian specific, but "apt-get install dovecot postfix" should get you to where you can use this:

http://rimuhosting.com/support/settingupemail.jsp?mta=postfix

and for virtual users and dovecot: 
http://wiki.dovecot.org/VirtualUsers

Comment: The workaround tutorial got me up and running with postfix+dovecot back when it was a sarge tutorial. +1

Answer (score 0):

I have posted one on [my wiki](http://www.tekevo.net/doku.php?id=pfx:installation) but it's in French. You can always use Google Translate to translate it but it works really well.

Answer (score 0):

I find there's a lot of good sysadmin tutorials on [HowToForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/), including several [Postfix](http://www.howtoforge.com/howtos/email/postfix) ones.

You will sometimes have to read tutorials for other distros, but they're not hard to make the slightly different steps work (ie replace yum for apt-get sometimes is all you need to do).

Here's one that looks like what you exactly want:
[Groupware Server With Group-Office, Postfix, Dovecot And SpamAssassin On Debian Lenny (5.0)](http://www.howtoforge.com/groupware-server-with-group-office-postfix-dovecot-spamassassin-on-debian-lenny)

Answer (score 0):

Not Debian, but still, Ubuntu's not that far off -- I found this tutorial very helpful: http://craigballinger.com/blog/2009/07/postfix-dovecot-mailserver-on-ubuntu-904-jaunty-jackalope/

Answer (score 0):

Great Tut:
http://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny

work for me like a charme wih 400 Mailboxes and 100G Mails...